# How to transform Source code to code tree in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've got a source code which I´d like to modify and reuse. The picture shows an example (not my website). I've got stuck for a while with the simple task of displaying the code not as a flowing text but as an actual code tree. Excuse my lack of basic skills; everyone starts somewhere. Appreciate your responses and guidance.

[image]

Already tried to find the settings in VSC without results. Also, lacking the correct terminology, I couldn't find any information through google, AIs or YouTube. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: just **Format** the document, it will improve a lot, except for the minified names

Comment: Yey! 100 points for you!! That finally worked - may you always have helpful people around you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use the prettier of vscode extension.

Here is the link
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Please install the extension and follow the doc to format the file.

Comment: Thanks. That didn´t do the job. Appreciate anyways.